# Strange abstraction behaviour - boolean() returns false while

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to perform some basic logic on my application which checks the entities position to call an enter/exit method however I'm getting some strange results:

```
Contains false - Compare true
```

Where the following method prints the results

```
@Override
public void checkLocation(Player player) {
    System.out.println("Contains " + contains(player) + " - Compare ${inLocation(player.position)}");
}
```

The contains boolean:

```
@Override
public boolean contains(Player player) {
     return inLocation(player.position);
}
```

I don't understand how contains(player) returns false, while the inLocation(player.position) returns true? Really stomping on my understanding of how things work.

The code is in groovy. `${var}` is just groovy's way of concatenating.

Comment: Interesting. Please provide an example the reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context of your code it is possible that groovy's contains method is being called on the class/controller/service  that this code exists in, instead of calling your defined contains method. Maybe it is implicitly calling

`this.contains(player)`

Try changing your method name to "hasPlayer()" or add a println inside your contains method to ensure that code is being called.